# End to end in for_each

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c++11, iterator

For a `std::for_each` call, is it legal to have both iterators be the end iterator? For example,

```
std::vector<int> some_ints;
std::for_each(ints.end(), ints.end(), [&](int i) {
    std::cout << i;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is perfectly legal and produces an empty range.  The result will be that nothing happens but the behavior is well defined.

Here is a relevant quote from the SGI reference page on iterators and their use as ranges ([Documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Iterators.html))

> Most algorithms are expressed not in terms of a single iterator but in terms of a range of iterators; the notation [first, last) refers to all of the iterators from first up to, but not including, last. Note that a range may be empty, i.e. **first and last may be the same iterator.**